# Problems loading pages and images using 'href' and 'src'

Tags: html

I'm having trouble setting up the proper paths for my website, using 'href', I keep getting the 404 error when I'm on the github pages for it, but while developing on live server it works perfectly, making it hard to get what am I doing wrong. for example, on the root of the site I have the index.html and a couple other pages, those work with no problems, but then I created a folder to hold the other pages (called 'sub-pages') but everything I put on there does not get redirected at all, giving me the 404 error. for example, If i do href="index.html" it works, but if I do href="pages/sub-pages/page" I get 404'd while on the gitpages but on the live server it works no problem

Comment: Hi Lucas, great question about HTML src= and 404 errors. If possible could you edit your question and include any example code that you are using. It is OK if the code does not work, it will still help others find an answer for you. Have a great weekend. Rob.

Answer (score 0):

The way a path is interpreted is different according to the system.
Try href="./[subfolder]/page.[extension]"

Comment: I tried it, it kind of worked, but it only diplays the html of the site now, and the paths for the css are loading fine on live server but not on gitpages this time.

Comment: Can you provide your code because it isn't easy to see.